# Preterite vs Imperfect of quedar

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto

Pablo Neruda, nacido en Chile in 1904, estuvo en contacto directo con la naturaleza desde su infancia, sentimiento que quedó reflejado en su obra.

Why can't quedaba be used in place of quedó?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His books are already written so this nature feeling is past because it is already in his books "quedó reflejado en su obra", and "quedaba" means that it was in his books while he was writing but just in that time, not anymore.